# How to get count of particular column value from total number of records and display difference in two different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get difference between total records and a column (Is_Registered) to get Month wise matrics of how many registered in particular month and how many are pending

Actual Data

```
| Inserted On | IsRegistered |
+-------------+--------------+
| 10-01-2020  | 1            |
| 15-01-2020  | 1            |
| 17-01-2020  | null         |
| 17-02-2020  | 1            |
| 21-02-2020  | null         |   
| 04-04-2020  | null         |
| 18-04-2020  | null         |
| 19-04-2020  | 1            |
```

Expected Output -As shown in actual data, out of 8 users(records) 2 are registered in Jan and 6 are not ,in February total 3 are registered i.e. Jan's 2 + Feb's 1 and 5 are not and so on

```
| Year     | Month          | Registered  | Not Registered |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- | -------------- |
| 2020     | January        | 2           | 6              |
| 2020     | Feb            | 3           | 5              |
| 2020     | April          | 4           | 4              |
```

But when a new record is added with new month then it should not update previous output result e.g. After adding new record with month as May and IsReg as NULL the value for Not_Registered should be as mentioned below because the new record is added in new month.

```
| Year     | Month          | Registered  | Not Registered |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- | -------------- |
| 2020     | January        | 2           | 6              |
| 2020     | Feb            | 3           | 5              |
| 2020     | April          | 4           | 4              |
| 2020     | May            | 4           | 5              |
```

And if the new record has month as May and Is_Registered as 1(true) then the output should be as follows

```
| Year     | Month          | Registered  | Not Registered |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- | -------------- |
| 2020     | January        | 2           | 6              |
| 2020     | Feb            | 3           | 5              |
| 2020     | April          | 4           | 4              |
| 2020     | May            | 5           | 4              |
```

I managed to write a query but didn't got expected output, what changes I'll have to make in order to get expected output

```
select year(dateinserted) as [Year], datename(month,dateinserted) as [Month],
coalesce(sum(cast(isregistered as int)), 0) as Authenticated,
sum(case when isregistered is null then 1 else 0 end) as UnAuthenticated
from table_name where IsRegistered is not null
group by year(dateinserted), datename(month,dateinserted)
order by year(dateinserted), month(min(dateinserted));

Output I got after executing above query -

| Year     | Month          | Registered  | Not Registered |
| -------- | -------------- | ----------- | -------------- |
| 2020     | January        | 2           | 1              |
| 2020     | Feb            | 1           | 1              |
| 2020     | April          | 1           | 2              |
```

Comment: Where is your users table? You need to join that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want a cumulative sum of the counts (which are `1` or `NULL`, so `count()` works).  For the second column, then difference between that and the total number of rows:

```
select year(dateinserted) as [Year],
       datename(month, dateinserted) as [Month],
       count(isregistered) as registered_in_month,
       sum(count(isregistered)) over (order by min(dateinserted)) as registered_up_to_month,
       sum(count(*)) over () - sum(count(isregistered)) over (order by min(dateinserted)) as not_yet_registered
from table_name 
group by year(dateinserted), datename(month, dateinserted)
order by year(dateinserted), month(min(dateinserted));
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0026071ddeebf90aeb9e1c8f54971de) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried this query but didn't got expected output 

`| Year     | Month         | Reg_In_Month | Reg_up_to_month | not_yet_reg |
 | --------   | --------------  | -------------------- | ------------------------- | --------------- |
 | 2020     | January      | 2                       | 2                             | 0                 |
 | 2020     | Feb             | 1                       | 3                             | 1                 |
 | 2020     | April            | 1                       | 4                             | -1                | `

Comment: apologies for formatting of previous comment ,  Not_yet_reg gave {|1 |-0|-1|} as output , but the expected output was supposed to be Not_yet_reg {|6 |5|4||}

Comment: @VishalD . . . I didn't even notice that your code had a `where` clause.  There was another bug, which I fixed, and added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked on my dummy table let me check on actual table which have more than 10K row 

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff...The query gave expected output, but when I tested with another scenario where I added new row with new date I noticed something weird ,actually I should have mentioned this case while posting the question. I added new record , the not_yet_reg column's previous records were updated i.e. before adding the values were  {|6 |5|4|} and after adding new record with month as May and IsReg as NULL the values were updated to {|7|6|5|4} ,as per the requirement it should have been {|6|5|4|5|} because the new record was added in May

Comment: @VishalD . . . Ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use self join and analytical function as follows:

```
Select year(t.inserted_on) as yr,
       datename(month, t.dateinserted) as mnth,
       Sum(count(t.is_registered)) 
           over (order by min(t.inserted_on)) as resistered,
       Tt.cnt - Sum(count(t.is_registered))
                    over (order by min(t.inserted_on)) as not_registered
  From your_table t
  Join (select t.*,
               Count(*) over () as cnt
          From your_table t) tt on t.inserted_on = tt.inserted_on 
group by year(t.dateinserted), datename(month, t.dateinserted), tt.cnt
order by year(t.dateinserted), month(min(t.dateinserted));
```